# Need help in transferring a file using Email/Bluetooth/Social Network

Tags: c++, qt, n900

Hey guys, I need some general information on how can I use Qt to send a file using email or bluetooth or a social network already defined in the N900 (e.g. facebook) ..

Regarding bluetooth, I read that Qt doesn't provide any libraries, and you would have to use Qt Extended, or use the default Maemo libraries ...

I also know that for general phone functions, a DBus can be used to perform the necessary functions .. I need help in fully understanding this DBus concept and how to use it to transfer files ... And regarding uploading a file to a social network already defined in the N900, I have no idea ...

Any general help on these three points would be really appreciated .. !

Answer (score 0):

hello i will try to answer all your questions :

to send a mail you can use some third party library like http://www.vmime.org/ one that works on n900 you could also try qt desktop services http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdesktopservices.html#details or look in the messaging module of qt mobility api http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/messaging.html, 
for bluetooth search the mobility api's http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0/service-frameworks.html or use the n900 api's and for uploading a file you should study the api of the social network you want to work with and use http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html to do post and get operations.

hope that helped :D